# How to groupby unique values from elasticsearch with grafana

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, group-by, grafana, grafana-variable

Info:

Grafana 7.5.7
Elastic 7.11
Linux OS

I would like to know how can I get unique values from elasticsearch with Grafana’s query editor.

My Query's Data is the following:

- Query: $snort
- Metric: Count
- Groupby: Terms -> event.sms -> Top 10, OrderBy: Term value
- ThenBy: Date Histogram -> @timestamp -> Interval:auto

https://i.stack.imgur.com/niONc.png

As you can see from the above picture it shows **SSH Detected** several times in my dashboard and I wish it just once.

Thanks!